# Can we achieve 'Filtering on Examples' based on karate.env

Tags: karate

Can we achieve 'Filtering on Examples' that we have on [Jbehave](https://jbehave.org/reference/latest/meta-filtering.html)

**Sample below:**

```
* def request = { item: '#(item)' }
Examples:
|karate.env:     |item                |
|@dev            |778983-110833-110834|
|@qa             |848079-419456-419457|
```

What we need to achieve is:

1. Karate DSL to execute the tests in Examples table based on the
   current value of karate.env
2. Karate must create a request = `{ item:
   '778983-110833-110834' }` if i run tests in dev environment & `{ item:
   '848079-419456-419457' }` if i run tests in qa.

---

I was unable to achieve this by using karate.env property but achieved it using the tags, please refer to example below:

```
Feature:

  Background:
    * url 'https://reqres.in/api'
    * configure headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

  Scenario Outline:
    * def reqJson = { "name": "name", "job": "<item>"}
    And path 'users'
    And request reqJson
    When method post
    Then status 201
    And match response.job == '<item>'

    @dev
    Examples:
      | item |
      |   111|

   @qa
    Examples:
      | item |
      |   222|
```

Triggering on commandline for environment=qa :  `mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @qa"`
  Triggering on commandline for environment=dev :  `mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @dev"`

Please let me know if there is any other  way of achieving it since i wanted to use karate.env property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#tags-and-examples

> A little-known capability of the Cucumber / Gherkin syntax is to be able to tag even specific rows in a bunch of examples ! You have to repeat the Examples section for each tag. The example below combines this with the advanced features described above.

```
Scenario Outline: examples partitioned by tag
* def vals = karate.tagValues
* match vals.region[0] == '<expected>'

  @region=US
  Examples:
    | expected |
    | US       |

  @region=GB
  Examples:
    | expected |
    | GB       |
```

EDIT: for those landing here trying to do this, I suggest another approach, you can call a feature like this:

```
* call read('foo-' + karate.env + '.feature')
```

Remember, Karate can read from JSON (or CSV) files and you can use that to drive `Examples:` https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline

And finally, I don't recommend this much - but if you want to achieve the logic to NOT run a test for a particular `karate.env` value, you can do this via [`karate.abort()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-abort):

```
* if (karate.env == 'prod') karate.abort()
```

Just add that line just after the `Scenario:` and the test will be skipped when needed.

Comment: Thanks, i will try it out

Comment: [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143475/peter-thomas) : I have added my comments with a working example in my question above , please validate it and confirm if there is a way to use 'karate.env' in tags to achieve it.

Comment: @Sud what you have done is correct. tags are for filtering. karate.env is for switching config. you seem to be confused between the two. if you really want to use ONLY karate.env, use if conditions, refer the doc on "conditional logic"

Comment: I looked at the 'conditional logic' on docs. Tags work better for our use case here. I was expecting something like @karate.env=dev in tags but feel its a too much of an ask. :)

Comment: @Sud - karate is open source, you can contribute code instead of ask :P

Comment: for those landing here trying to do this, I suggest another approach, you can call a feature like this: `* call read('foo-' + karate.env + '.feature')` - remember karate can read from JSON (or CSV) files and you can use that to drive `Examples`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline