# Is it possible to add tags for each row in table data

Tags: karate

@case1
Scenario: CreateDog Testcases

- table CreateDog

  |testcaseName|name|gender|status

  |"Test for Male Dog"|"Titus"|"male"|201|

  |"Test for Male Dog"|"Serena"|"female"|201|
- string jsonStringForCreateDog = CreateDog
- JavaUtil.writeJsonToFile(jsonStringForCreateDog, "CreateDog.json")

I have a feature file that uses a table to create data for each of the test cases for a particular usecase. The actual test feature file then reads the json file created from the above step in the scenario outline example and runs all the tests for which the data is available in the json file.
I do not want to generate the data for some of the rows in the table above when run on a particular test environment. Is there a way to add tags for each row ? Or is there any other options to achieve this?

Comment: Formatting code properly with the editor and providing a minimal reproducible example may help to get this question answered. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Also adding more tags for visibility will help

Comment: other relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55479614/143475

Comment: @PeterThomas - is this applicable for table as well? If so, should I repeat '* table xxx' after the tag?  In other words, would it be like '@ttt' and next line  '* table xxx' ? And later generate * string jsonString = xxx ?

Comment: @asasi no. a `table` has nothing to do with `Examples` or tags. please read the docs.

Comment: @PeterThomas- Could you please guide me on how to ignore certain rows of data in  a table while running. In our tests, we create test data as a JSON using the table. But in some cases (eg. Some featured flag is off), we do not want to generate data for some rows of the table. I was thinking if tagging might be an option. Please let me know what is the best way to achieve this.